# what is the name of design pattern illustrated in this code?

Tags: design-patterns

from the code below, is this an exemple of Iterator design pattern ?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I think it is called a Factory?

Comment: Iterator, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern

Comment: @OrelEraki thanks Glad I had the same thought :D